# Contact template doesnt appear in page template options

Tags: page-template

I want to make a custom contact page with a custom template. But when I create the page i dont get the option to select my Contact-template. What did i do wrong that It wont appear?

Here is the basic structure of my contact-template.php:

```
<?php 
/*  
Template Name: Contact template 
*/
get_header();

?>

<p>Contact page</p>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I did it the same way for my custom home and blog page and those get listed in the options.

Comment: Where did you place this file in the theme?

Comment: its in the main folder where the other templates are

Comment: I took the code you give and made a `contact-template.php` in my test theme. Worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Page templates require only a few things to work:

1. To be in the theme's (or child theme's) directory. Either in the root directory or in a subfolder.
2. To have appropriate permissions (It will need to be read by WordPress, usually www user). Typically it should have the permission [644 or 640](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions).
3. To have a Template name header

From the question and comments you have (1) and (3), so the file you have created presumably has the wrong file permissions.

Comment: I thought only two level deep directory search is done. Can we keep file any where in the theme?

Comment: @bravokeyl - you're right. Root folder or sub-folder( https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/cd6d2bae9200f4d2cfc3c0dc974a34f94bf0ad27/wp-includes/class-wp-theme.php#L1026). My 'anywhere' statement was based on the lack of documentation (I could find) to clarify that, and I only tested root and 1 level down.